# How to do an out on multiple variables in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, variables, out

I would like to do an `out` on multiple variables from a dictionary as in the following example:

```
string color;
int number;
float numval;

Dictionary<string, (string, int, float)> Property = new Dictionary<string, (string, int, float)>();

Property.Add("G", ("Green", 2, (float)2.99));

Property.TryGetValue("G", out(color, number, numval));
```

When I tried to use `TryGetValue`, I got this error:

> An out or ref value must be an assignable variable

I know I could use a Tuple, instead of multiple values ​​like this, but I want it to work like that.

Comment: This is not yet supported, [see the discussion here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/611). The best you can do is `TryGetValue("G", out var value); var (color, number, numval) = value;`

Comment: Move your values into a class, then your dictionary becomes `Dictionary<key, value>` like it's supposed to be.   Your `tryget` will work (because you have a single value), and everyone will understand your code (even you, in 6 months time).

Comment: @Glubus It makes use of `ValueTuple`, not `Tuple` -- there's no mention of `Tuple` anywhere in the question, or my code

Comment: @canton7 yea you;re right I was confused, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a tuple in a dictionary like that.. but if you really need to, you can do this:

```cs
Dictionary<string, (string, int, float)> Property = new Dictionary<string, (string, int, float)>();

Property.Add("G", ("Green", 2, 2f));

if(Property.TryGetValue("G", out var val))
{
    string color = val.Item1;
    int number = val.Item2;
    float numval = val.Item3;

    // or as @canton7 suggested in the comments:
    var (color, number, numVal) = val;
}
```